# What is the Java code for opening an incognito window and going to an URL?

Tags: java

I'm new to java. So this is the code i found to open a web page in default browser. I need it to open an incognito window in chrome and then go to the URL.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

public class OpenWebPage {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            URI uri= new URI("https://www.google.com");
            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
            System.out.println("Web page opened in browser");

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is just asking the OS to open an URI using the default application. So you are not in control of the browser, the OS and the user configuration is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;  
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;


public class Sel{

public static void main(String[] args) {


System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

// Initialize browser

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--incognito");

WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
// Open facebook
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();


}

}
```

This being the entire code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I think it can help.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--incognito");
```

See [ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/home) from WebDriver and [this](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities).

Comment: What is the library used here ? Note that other browser use incognito mode so this might be restrictive.

Comment: You can use webdriver for this.

Comment: I don't think he's using Selenium

Comment: I don't want to do anything but improve your answer's quality ;)